# ApexChart Candlestick update candle

Tags: updating, apexcharts, candlestick-chart

I am trying to update an existing candle and trying to set new (open, high, low, close)
I tried many codes but none of them is working.

Here are my efforts

```js
var chart;
options = {
    series: [{
  data: [{
    x: new Date(2016, 01, 01),
    y: [51.98, 56.29, 51.59, 53.85]
  },
  {
    x: new Date(2016, 02, 01), // This candle I am trying to update.
    y: [53.66, 54.99, 51.35, 52.95]
  },
  {
    x: new Date(2016, 08, 01),
    y: [52.76, 57.35, 52.15, 57.03]
  }]
}],
    chart: {
        type: 'candlestick',
        height: 350
    },
    title: {
        text: 'BTC USDT',
        align: 'left'
    },
    xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
    },
    yaxis: {
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
};
chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
    chart.render();
chart.appendData({ // not updating existing candle
data: [{
    x: new Date(2016, 02, 01),
    y: [51.98, 56.29, 51.59, 60]
  }]
});

chart.addPointAnnotation({// not working
    x: new Date(2016, 02, 01),
    y: [51.98, 56.29, 51.59, 60]
});

chart.updateSeries([{ // NOT working
data: [{
    x: new Date(2016, 02, 01),
    y: [51.98, 56.29, 51.59, 60]
  }]
}]);
    

/* chart.appendSeries({ // This is not updating same time candle
  animation: false,
  data: [{
    x: new Date(2016, 01, 01),
    y: [51.98, 56.29, 51.59, 49.85]
  }]
}) */
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
```

```
    y: [51.98, 56.29, 51.59, 53.85]
  },
  {
    x: new Date(2016, 02, 01),
    y: [53.66, 54.99, 51.35, 52.95]
  },
  {
    x: new Date(2016, 08, 01),
    y: [52.76, 57.35, 52.15, 57.03]
  }]
}],
    chart: {
        type: 'candlestick',
        height: 350
    },
    title: {
        text: 'BTC USDT',
        align: 'left'
    },
    xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
    },
    yaxis: {
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
};
chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
    chart.render();
chart.appendData({ // not updating existing candle
data: [{
    x: new Date(2016, 02, 01),
    y: [51.98, 56.29, 51.59, 60]
  }]
});

chart.addPointAnnotation({// not working
    x: new Date(2016, 02, 01),
    y: [51.98, 56.29, 51.59, 60]
});

chart.updateSeries([{ // NOT working
data: [{
    x: new Date(2016, 02, 01),
    y: [51.98, 56.29, 51.59, 60]
  }]
}]);
    

/* chart.appendSeries({ // This is not updating same time candle
  animation: false,
  data: [{
    x: new Date(2016, 01, 01),
    y: [51.98, 56.29, 51.59, 49.85]
  }]
}) */
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been fiddling with ApexCharts for the last couple of days, trying to solve a similar issue.

I'm getting the updates via WebSocket API using a web worker, so the connection doesn't get sleepy after a while/on inactivity. What I found that works for a candle update was the following:

```js
  let candlestick;
  let nextTimestamp = getNextTimestamp(initialChartData[initialChartData.length - 1].x);

  worker.onmessage = event => {
    candlestick = this.transformDataKraken(event.data);
  }

  // Set up chart update
  setInterval(() => {
    if (!candlestick) return;

    const chartData = options.series[0].data;

    if (candlestick.x < nextTimestamp) {
      // Update candlestick
      candlestick.x.setSeconds(0, 0);
      chartData[chartData.length - 1] = candlestick;
    } else {
      // Time's up, add new candlestick
      chartData.shift();
      chartData.push(candlestick);

      nextTimestamp = getNextTimestamp(nextTimestamp);
    }

    chart.updateSeries([{
      data: chartData
    }]);
  }, 1000);
```

getNextTimestamp just adds 60 sec to the passed value.

I still however have some problems with the chart acting weird and compressing the candles' width after some time has passed/tab been inactive, as if the array size has changed when it clearly hasn't.